# Perl - Convert PC UTF-8 to PC ANSI

Tags: perl, unicode, ansi

I have a file that is encoded PC UTF-8. I would like to convert the file into PC ANSI.

I have tried the below, but I always get the output file to be PC UTF-8.

```
use Encode;

$infile = $ARGV[0];
open(INFILE, $infile);

my $outfile = "temp.txt";

open(OUTFILE, ">$outfile");

while(<INFILE>) {
  my $row = $_;
  chomp $row;

  $row = Encode::encode("Windows-1252", $row);
  print OUTFILE $row."\n";

}

close INFILE;
close OUTFILE;
```

Comment: It's *slightly* wasteful to `chomp` the line and then append `\n` to it.

Comment: Can you try it with a *very* small file, say 1 short line with a single non-ASCII character, and show us a hex dump of the input and the output?

Comment: And this isn't relevant to your problem, but the 3-argument version of `open` is preferred. http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you never decode the data you encode.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode qw( encode decode );

open(my $INFILE,  '<', $ARGV[0]) or die $!;
open(my $OUTFILE, '>', $ARGV[1]) or die $!;

while (my $utf8 = <$INFILE>) {
   my $code_points = decode('UTF-8', $utf8);    # <-- This was missing.
   my $cp1252 = encode('cp1252', $code_points);
   print $OUTFILE $cp1252;
}
```

But you can do this a bit more easily:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $INFILE,  '<:encoding(UTF-8)',  $ARGV[0]) or die $!;
open(my $OUTFILE, '>:encoding(cp1252)', $ARGV[1]) or die $!;

while (<$INFILE>) {
   print $OUTFILE $_;
}
```

Comment: (`cp1252` is just a shorter way of writing `Windows-1252`)

Comment: This seems to work. I just get a message with ""\x{feff}" does not map to cp1252". Any nice way of filtering these out?

Comment: If that's the only problem character, you can safely get rid of it using `s/^\x{FEFF}//;` (after decoding). It's the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Transcoding and replacing some of the contents is not such a rare scenario, for example if you are working on files that includes the encoding in the meta data like HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing decoding and encoding manually, you should use PerlIO-Layers. You can specify a layer with the `binmode` function, or in the mode argument to three-arg `open`:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $INFILE,  '<:utf8',                 $ARGV[0];
open my $OUTFILE, '>:encoding(iso-8859-1)', "temp.txt";
#                   ^-- the layers

while (my $line = <$INFILE>) {
  print $OUTFILE $line;
}
```

Note that Perl doesn't open files to UTF8 by default, and you have to specify the decoding layer as well. The layer `:encoding(utf8)` is so common, that you can say `:utf8` directly.

You can list all available encodings with

```
use Encode;
print "$_\n" for Encode->encodings();
```

Comment: @user333746 ① Check the list of available encodings, to see what you have currently installed. ② Please compare your code to my updated post; The layer is `:encoding(foo-bar)` (my initial post had a mistake). ③ What version of perl are you running? Why an `eval` – are you under mod_perl?

Comment: Why did you change from Windows-1252 to iso-8859-1? They're not the same, and the OP clearly said he wanted the "ANSI" encoding (which is what Windows calls it's single-byte local encoding, which is Windows-1252 aka cp1252 on most machines, neve iso-8859-1).